# ¿Cómo cambiar los argumentos/texto de una leyenda?

Tags: r, texto

Estoy haciendo un gráfico de barras, las variables del eje x están resumidas, ejemplo NO, C+G, etc. pero quisiera que en la leyenda estén los nombres extendidos Sin disturbio (en lugar de NO), castor y ganado (C+G), etc. Me podrías ayudar a hacerlo?

```
ggplot(aes(disturbio, Estrato_max, fill= disturbio)) + 
  stat_summary(fun = mean, geom = "bar", color="black", 
               width=0.5) + 
  stat_summary(fun.data = mean_se, geom = "errorbar", 
               color="black", width=0.5) + 
  scale_x_discrete(limits = c("NO", "AF", "PF", "C_G", "C_I", "I","M")) +
  labs(y = "Estrato máximo", x = "Disturbio", 
       color = "Disturbio") + 
  theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white", color = "black"), 
        panel.grid = element_blank(), strip.text = element_text(face = "bold"), 
        legend.position = "right")
```

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: ggplot(aes(disturbio, Estrato_max, fill= disturbio)) +
  stat_summary(fun = mean, geom = "bar",
               color="black", width=0.5) +
  stat_summary(fun.data = mean_se, geom = "errorbar",
               color="black", width=0.5) +
  scale_x_discrete(limits = c("NO", "AF", "PF", "C_G", "C_I", "I","M"))+
  labs(y = "Estrato máximo", x = "Disturbio", color = "Disturbio") +
  theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white", color = "black"),
        panel.grid = element_blank(),
        strip.text = element_text(face = "bold"),
        legend.position = "right")

Comment: tengo esa salida para hacer un grafico, pero me gustaría que la leyenda contenga otro textos (no me deja pegar la imagen del gráfico). En vez de las variables que estan en el eje x scale_x_discrete(limits = c("NO", "AF", "PF", "C_G", "C_I", "I","M")) que muestre otros nombre.

Comment: disculpa si no puedo ser más precisa, soy nueva en esto..

Answer (score 0):

Pueds cambiar las etiquetas con el argumento `labels` de `scale_x_discrete` por ejemplo:

```r
scale_x_discrete(
  limits = c("NO", "AF", "PF", "C_G", "C_I", "I","M"),
  labels = c("Sin disturbio", "Texto1", "Texto2", "Castor y Ganado", "Texto3", "Texto4", "Texto5")
)
```